# Replicate Default Flex 4 style in Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex-spark, halo

I was wondering if anyone has run across a style or stylesheet replicating the default Flex 4 style (Spark) over to Flex 3.  I love the cleaner and less blue look of Flex 4, but I have to develop an application with Flex 3 for compatibility purposes.

Answer (score 0):

By default all mx components now take on the spark theme.

***'The default theme for Flex 3 (MX) components is now the Spark theme.'***
See Here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex3and4_differences.html --> search for 'Theme change'.

also...

***Alternatively, the theme can be changed from the default Spark theme to Halo in the Properties -> Flex Theme panel. In the “Flex Theme” panel, click on the Halo theme***

Hope this helps...

-Burton